# Is it left align or right align data?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, pixel

I  captured an Image using Ethernet camera. The image is 12bit. I confirmed this by opening the raw data in a hex editor. To get the saturated values, I put a white paper under a white light and captured the image. The data is coming like this:

```
 (FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)(FF)(0F)
```

and so on.

Is it left align or right align? Do I need to take care of overflow during some processing on this image?   If yes how?

Comment: Did my answer help you with finding your solution???

Answer (score 0):

Standard imager convention is for data to go from left-to-right top-to-bottom.  My guess is that while your imager is a 12 bit sensor, it aligns the output data in 16 bit format for ease of looking at the data so that you dont have to perform any data shifting etc...

I think your real values are: 0x0FFF thus you will need to byte swap to get your real 16 bit values.